# Save Activerecord model if there are no changed attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `before_save` callback.
Activerecord `save()` method runs only when there is at least one changed attribute.
How to run `before_save` callback if there are no attributes changed?

Comment: I think you can use after_validation for this purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use `after_validation` instead of `before_save`